# tkinter Treeview memory leek

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, memory, memory-leaks, tcl

This is my code:

```py
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import Tk, Button

def destroy_root():
    global tree, root
    # tree.delete(*tree.get_children()) # Doesn't help, actually increases memory usage
    tree.destroy()
    root.destroy()
    del tree
    del root

root = Tk()

Button(root, text="Destroy root", command=destroy_root).pack()

tree = ttk.Treeview(root)
tree.pack()
tree["columns"] = ["0"]

for i in range(1000000):
    tree.insert("", "end", i, values=(i, ))

root.mainloop()
```

When I run the problem, it uses 452 MB of RAM:

[image: 452 MB of RAM]

When I press the `"Destroy root"` button, it still uses 444 MB of RAM:

[image]

Why is that? Shouldn't the memory usage drop to less than 100 MB?

Furthermore, if I delete the items inside the treeview before destroying it, the memory usage rises to more than 600 MB:

[image: 659 MB of RAM]

Does that mean that there is a memory leak somewhere inside `tkinter`/`tcl`?

Comment: It looks like it's something about Python Shell. If you run the script through cmd (`python file.py`) or by double-clicking the file, then after clicking the button, this process disappears. If you open and run the file through Python IDLE, this process remains in Task Manager until you close the Python Shell window. If you add `exit()` after the `root.mainloop()`, then the Shell message appears after clicking the button (Your program is still running! Do you want to kill it?).

Comment: Same for other Python scripts (not tkinter), two processes for pythonw.exe. Also wondering how it works.

Comment: Not necessarily. It might just be the high-water-mark memory allocator. (When there's a lot of small memory allocations, determining when to return memory to the OS is really quite difficult.) Make sure your OS has plenty of space for its page file to grow into.

Comment: But I can confirm that destroying a widget _by any mechanism you can come up with_ should always properly destroy its children as well.

Comment: @8349697 Add `input(">>> ")` to the end of the code and run it through any cmd/double clicking

Comment: @DonalFellows Ok but why does the used RAM increase when I use `tree.delete(*tree.get_children())`. That doesn't make sense. Also given that I destroy the `tcl` interpreter when I run `root.destroy()` and remove all references to that interpreter, shouldn't it force python to give the memory back to the OS. PS: I don't know much about how the heap is allocated.

Comment: @DonalFellows Also your theory is most likely correct because if instead of destroying the treeview, I delete all of the items on it and recreate them, the memory usage stays constant

Comment: I do know the memory allocator it's using; it's using a per-thread arena (greatly reduces the scope of locks required elsewhere in the code) and never releases memory to the OS (because that's nasty to get right). Part of what Tkinter does is interfacing that memory model to the very different one used in Python.

Comment: It looks like the Python process [won't give anything back](https://realpython.com/python-memory-management/#cpythons-memory-management).

Comment: @8349697 Thx. That means that it's cpython's fault for not letting go of the memory. I would consider it a bug.