# Python Tkinter Treeview with Memory Leak?

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I have been trying to solve this problem/puzzle for what feels like a week. I hope someone can explain the one key point and help me solve it. I have created an example here where you can see everything in detail.

Problem:

- Start script, memory size is at 9.9 MB.
- I click on "Insert 50000 records", memory size is now 37.8MB.
- I click on "Insert 10 records", memory size now at 46.7MB doesn't get smaller
- I click on "Insert 10 records" again, the memory size doesn't get smaller.

=> even if I destroy the treeview with "Delete Tree", the memory does not get smaller (despite the active GC command).

Thank you very much for your efforts.

brMr

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import gc

gc.enable()

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.initialize_user_interface()
 
    def initialize_user_interface(self):
        # Configure the root object for the Application
        self.root.title("Application")
        self.root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.root.config(background="lightgrey")
 
        # Define the different GUI widgets
        self.name_label = tk.Label(self.root, text="Name:")
        self.name_entry = tk.Entry(self.root)
        self.name_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
        self.name_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
 
        self.idnumber_label = tk.Label(self.root, text="ID:")
        self.idnumber_entry = tk.Entry(self.root)
        self.idnumber_label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
        self.idnumber_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)
 
        self.submit_button1 = tk.Button(self.root, text="Insert 50000 records", command=self.insert_data50000times)
        self.submit_button1.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=tk.W)

        self.submit_button2 = tk.Button(self.root, text="Insert 10 records", command=self.insert_data10times)
        self.submit_button2.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=tk.W)
 
        self.delete_button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Create Tree", command=self.create_tree)
        self.delete_button.grid(row=100, column=100)

        self.delete_button_all = tk.Button(self.root, text="Delete Tree", command=self.delete_tree)
        self.delete_button_all.grid(row=200, column=100)
 
        self.exit_button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Exit", command=self.root.quit)
        self.exit_button.grid(row=0, column=3)
 
        # Set the treeview
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self.root, columns=('Name', 'ID'))
 
        # Set the heading (Attribute Names)
        self.tree.heading('#0', text='Item')
        self.tree.heading('#1', text='Name')
        self.tree.heading('#2', text='ID')
 
        # Specify attributes of the columns (We want to stretch it!)
        self.tree.column('#0', stretch=tk.YES)
        self.tree.column('#1', stretch=tk.YES)
        self.tree.column('#2', stretch=tk.YES)
 
        self.tree.grid(row=4, columnspan=4, sticky='nsew')
        self.treeview = self.tree
 
        self.id = 0
        self.iid = 0
 
    def insert_data50000times(self):
        for item in self.tree.get_children():
            self.tree.delete(item)
        i = 1
        while i < 50001:
            self.treeview.insert('', 'end', iid=self.iid, text="Item_" + str(self.id),
                                values=("Name: " + self.name_entry.get(),
                                        self.idnumber_entry.get()))
            self.iid += 1
            self.id += 1
            i += 1
        gc.collect()

    def insert_data10times(self):
        for item in self.tree.get_children():
            self.tree.delete(item)
        i = 1
        while i < 11:
            self.treeview.insert('', 'end', iid=self.iid, text="Item_" + str(self.id),
                                values=("Name: " + self.name_entry.get(),
                                        self.idnumber_entry.get()))
            self.iid += 1
            self.id += 1
            i += 1
        gc.collect()
 
    def create_tree(self):
        # Set the treeview
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self.root, columns=('Name', 'ID'))
 
        # Set the heading (Attribute Names)
        self.tree.heading('#0', text='Item')
        self.tree.heading('#1', text='Name')
        self.tree.heading('#2', text='ID')
 
        # Specify attributes of the columns (We want to stretch it!)
        self.tree.column('#0', stretch=tk.YES)
        self.tree.column('#1', stretch=tk.YES)
        self.tree.column('#2', stretch=tk.YES)
 
        self.tree.grid(row=4, columnspan=4, sticky='nsew')
        self.treeview = self.tree
        gc.collect()
    
    def delete_tree(self):
        self.tree.destroy()
        gc.collect()
 
app = Application(tk.Tk())
app.root.mainloop()
```

- Memory analyse with pympler: Nothing comes back here, the data always looks good and does not show anything out of the ordinary => except that the number of objects is getting bigger and bigger.
- Destroy tree
- Analyse input

Comment: I don't believe that tkinter releases the memory to the garbage collector. There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67950328/tkinter-treeview-memory-leek)

Comment: According to the comments on the question that @ OneMadGypsy linked, python doesn't give back any memory to the OS. Therefore, the memory might be free and reused by python but python still owns that memory. Also the `while` loops can be replaced with `for` loops. Did you try looking at `gc.set_debug(gc.DEBUG_LEAK)`?

Answer (score 0):

It's because Tcl/Tk(the backend of the `tkinter` module) implements a memory pool, which recycles small blocks. See [this](https://github.com/tcltk/tcl/blob/core-8-6-13/generic/tclThreadAlloc.c#L389) for details. The memory blocks in the pool will be reused on future Tcl calls. So it's not a memory leak.

Monitor the memory usage while repeating to create a treeview, insert items into it, and destroy the treeview.

This is a pure Tcl script that demonstrates that.

```
#!/usr/bin/wish
button .hello -text "exit" -command { exit }
pack .hello

button .create_tree -text "create tree" -command {
    if {![winfo exists .tree]} {
        ttk::treeview .tree
        pack .tree

        for { set i 0 } { $i < 100000 } { incr i } {
            .tree insert {} end -text "xxxxxx"
        }
    }
}
pack .create_tree

button .destroy_tree -text "destroy tree" -command {
    if {[winfo exists .tree]} {
        destroy .tree
    }
}
pack .destroy_tree
```